# What are fee_method and fee_level in Electrum's getfeerate RPC call?

Tags: transaction-fees, json-rpc, electrum, fee-estimation

I couldn't find any documentation on this.

I found that the options for fee_method are `eta`, `static` and `mempool` by reading the source code. But it's still not clear to me how `fee_level` relates to the `fee_method`, does it have something to do with configuration? If that's the case, the configuration isn't documented either. What is to be set? How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 options(fee estimation methods) available for `fee_method`: `static`, `eta` and `mempool`

`static` - static fees

`eta` - based on confirmation within N blocks

`mempool` - based on mempool depth

[image: electrum-fee-2]

`fee_level` for ETA can be one of these values in Electrum GUI: 25,10,5,2

```
FEE_ETA_TARGETS = [25, 10, 5, 2]
```

https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/ea22d0073ea5f61d53449a7afd072c3fd78003e8/electrum/simple_config.py#L23

[image: electrum-fee-1]

`fee_level` for Mempool can have one of the value mentioned below in Electrum GUI:

```
FEE_DEPTH_TARGETS = [10000000, 5000000, 2000000, 1000000, 500000, 200000, 100000]
```

https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/ea22d0073ea5f61d53449a7afd072c3fd78003e8/electrum/simple_config.py#L24

[image: electrum-fee-mempool]